# オンプレミス版GitLabでUsernameのみを表示する方法はありますか？

Tags: gitlab

オンプレミス版GitLabを導入したのですが、デフォルトで"Name"と"Username"が併記された状態になっています。
**"Username"のみを表示する設定は可能でしょうか？**
よろしくお願いします。

[image: MyGitLab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Username, Nameのどちらかを選択的に表示する機能は現在GitLabに存在せず、追加の要望が出ているとTwitterで教えていただきました。
この場をお借りして感謝申し上げます。

・GitLab Issue『Ability to show real names instead of username』
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17607